Ping identity -> integrations -> provisioning -> SCIM - auth fails
New to PingIdentity (have worked with Okta), and trying to set SCIM integration to my app.
My apps provides an API URL, and usually does authentication via header such as key=Authorization value="Basic TOKEN==".
I have this working with Okta, and also can simulate with Postman.
PingIdentity provides a few options for authentication, but so far none of those I tried worked - on Ping's audit logs it seems their SCIM call fails, and they either (1) get redirected to the interactive login page, or (2) get some other error.
The behavior changes with the auth type that I select for the integration.
EDIT: my actual question... any idea how to set (and debug) Ping SCIM? Thanks!
Some methods I tired:
OAuth2 Bearer Token:

Basic Authentication:

Basic Authentication with custom header:


Turns out my app didn't like Ping's User Filter Expression.
I cleaned it, now it's working.

